# login page redirect in angular validatioon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing, angularjs-forms

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {       
  $routeProvider.
  when('/success', {
    templateUrl: 'success.html',
    controller: 'sucCtrl'


  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/index'
  })
}])


app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope, $http, $location) {

  $scope.submit = function(user,password) {
    //for local storage validation

    $http.get('credentials.json').then(function(response) {
      $scope.credentials = response.data;

      if((user === $scope.credentials.username) && (password === $scope.credentials.password)){
        alert("ok");
         $location.path('/success');
      }

      else{
        alert("nit "); }



    });    


  };

})

app.controller('sucCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
  alert("succs");

}]);
```

This might be well a beginner question. I am trying to validate my login form and redirect to success.html on success. But I am unable to navigate to next page. I tried using $location.path('/success'). 
here is the working sample in plunker..
http://plnkr.co/edit/0v7njznHdtwgpaG2NfwA?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to write `ng-view` directive to get route changes to displayed on the view. Also you are messed up with the structuring of your page html. Refer below comments that will help you to make it working and improve it.

You should put that ng-view directive in body so that all the view will get loaded on basis of route changes.

Also you should load your form html from the route only, I'd suggest you to add one more route to your `config` that will say on `/login` show the `form.html`(login form)

**Config**

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {       
  $routeProvider.
  when('/success', {
    templateUrl: 'success.html',
    controller: 'sucCtrl'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'form.html',
    controller: 'validateCtrl'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/login'
  })
}])
```

**Markup**

```
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="login.controller.js"></script>
</body>
```

Your success.html should be partial, it shouldn't have the script references again to it they have been loaded from the index page only

**success.html**

```
<div>
  Success Message
</div>
```

[**Working Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/y2zNHiOuZjYtUjYz5WH9?p=preview)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I tried adding these changes. But on adding ng-view my plunker brower is crashing. Can you please help me

Comment: @user5304396 look like I putted wrong plunkr link..let me add the correct one..give me a minute

Comment: @user5304396 look at the udpated plunkr link Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. Works fine :)